# How to synchronize ElTreeItem with its checkbox(Radiobutton)?

Tags: delphi

Well, there is some problem I am having with this element.

Let ElTreeItem ShowCheckBox be true.

Click the ElTreeItem CheckBox(Radiobutton).

[image]

ElTree.Selected is nil(null)

Click the ElTreeItem Text(If its index = 2)

[image]

ElTree.Selected.Index = 2;

Click the ElTreeItem CheckBox(Radiobutton)(If it is in index = 0).

[image]

ElTree.Selected.Index = 2(still 2...)

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Hint: Use event handler.

Comment: Click Event?Is that your meaning?